# Error using dbms_xmlgen with clause with. I can't generate xml

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to generate a report with clause with and dbms_xmlgen but it gives me error:

```
ORA-19202
ORA-00942: table or view not exists
ORA-06512 at SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN
```

I do a complex query (for me) with clause with:

```sql
WITH PEPE AS
(
  SELECT jobtot,
         substr(avg_runtime, 1, 2) || ':' || substr(avg_runtime, 3, 2) AS "AVERAGE",
         trunc((sysdate - to_date(begin_time, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) * 1440) AS minutos_ejecutados,
         trim(to_char(trunc(trunc((sysdate -
                                  to_date(begin_time, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) * 1440) / 60),
                      '0999')) || ':' ||
         trim(to_char(trunc(mod(abs(trunc((sysdate -
                                          to_date(begin_time,
                                                   'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) * 1440)),
                                60)),
                      '09')) AS HHMM,
         substr(avg_runtime, 1, 2) * 60 + substr(avg_runtime, 3, 2) AS "AVGRUNTIME"
    FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE
   WHERE status = 'Executing'
     AND (sysdate - to_date(begin_time, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) * 1440 > 15
     AND task <> 'DOG'
     AND (sysdate - to_date(begin_time, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) * 1440 >
         2.5 * (substr(avg_runtime, 1, 2) * 60 + substr(avg_runtime, 3, 2))
   ORDER BY jobtot DESC
)
SELECT dbms_xmlgen.getXML('SELECT * FROM PEPE') QUERY_XML 
  FROM DUAL;
```

Any help please? Thanks

Comment: Sorry It's an example. I've edited the main post

Comment: `PEPE` is not available in the context of the inner query (this is a query string, which, of course, requires new parsing), because it is a separate cursor (and maybe session).

Comment: @astentx So... You mean I can't use dbms_xmlgen with a clause with? What do you think it's the best workaround? Thanks

Comment: You may put entire query inside it, but as long as you didn't specify the requirement, I cannot answer how get what you need.

Comment: @astentx Well it's a report. So I would like to generate in xml instead csv. Because of that, I would like to use dbms_xmlgen. I try with one query but it gives me errors like ORA-01745. So I thought make the query with clause with and then select all

Comment: There's no restriction on the query inside the function call, because it is treated as standalone query which then gets serialized in XML. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cb4785df9a2befa41ca19293d3e8581f)